# Java Email sending API email did not send.. hang up the program

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I was code a java email sending program. But when i click the send button the button appear hanging mode & program still running, but mail did not send.
I can't detect the problem. can anybody help me... 
The code is below.

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "false");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("myid@gmail.com", "password");
                }
            }
    );

    try {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("myid@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("senderid@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("Demo mail");
        message.setText("Hello, world!");
        Transport.send(message);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Message sent!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e);
    }
```

My email account have not activate 2-step verification service.
And it also work in outlook email sending software.. I tested.

But not work on my java program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the Authenticator class should be extended. Here is an example that works for me:

```
public class SendEmail {

    public SendEmail () {}

    public void send (String text){
        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        String username = "user@email.com";
        String password = "password";
        Properties props = new Properties();
        // set any needed mail.smtps.* properties here
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new GMailAuthenticator("user", "password"));
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        Transport t;
        try {
            msg.setText(text);
            msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("stackkinggame@gmail.com", "Stack King"));
            t = session.getTransport("smtps");
            t.connect(host, username, password);
            t.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
            t.close();
            Gdx.app.log("Email", "Message sent successfully.");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class GMailAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
        String user;
        String pw;
        public GMailAuthenticator (String username, String password)
        {
            super();
            this.user = username;
            this.pw = password;
        }
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
        {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(user, pw);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But it show this error....


javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
  nested exception is:
 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:

Comment: you must change the security parameter in your gmail account(https://www.google.com/settings/security) to let this application access to your account or use Gmail API

Answer (score 0):

First, fix all the [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes) in your program.

Second, since you're using Gmail, make sure you've [enabled support for less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps).

Finally, you need to provide more details than "it doesn't work".  The [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) would be helpful.